# macos external USB keyboard command key not working

Tags: keyboard, usb, shortcut

I have a reliable external keyboard that worked normally with a macbook pro (2018). I've upgraded to a new macbook air and the command key isn't working with the external keyboard. For example I can't use any keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> for spotlight. It appears to be just the command key.

Other examples:

- <kbd>⌘C</kbd>, <kbd>⌘V</kbd> not working
- <kbd>⌘,</kbd> for preferences not working
- Menu bar items (such as Edit > Copy) have the <kbd>⌘C</kbd> greyed out instead of black font.
- Other keys work normally: <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (for clearing terminal screen for example).
- Laptop keyboard working fine.

Attempted (failed) fixes:

- Reboot
- Reset SMC (also PRAM, NVRAM)
- Check USB connections on different ports
- Delete Libarary Prefs `com.apple.HIToolbox.plist`
- Repeat the keyboard detection (`Prefs > Keyboard > Change Keyboard Type...`)

Keyboard type:
Coolermaster Quicksight Rapid-i mechanical keyboard. I have used it successfully with work laptops (windows and macbook pro) as well as an iMac (2012).

Answer (score 10):

**Solution: Switch Modifier Key Assignment**

For some reason the new macbook is detecting the Command <kbd>⌘</kbd> key as <kbd>Alt</kbd> and vice-versa.

`Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys...` and switch the <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys.

Now it works. This was a painful experience so I'm sharing what I wish I had found online. I didn't discover that the command key was actually working until troubleshooting on https://keyboardchecker.com.

***The Menu list shortcuts are still greyed out***. I don't have a solution for this, but its cosmetic as the shortcuts still work, even ones I assign in keyboard prefs.

Comment: So for someone coming for this in future, Control on the keyboard becomes Command on modifier keys...

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this information. I was having a difficult time with this exact problem.

Comment: This just worked for me, only it was command and option that had to be switched instead of command and alt.